# Addition of new dict entry to tuple working but not new list?

Tags: python, tuples

Inspired from this riddle in "Fluent Python":

```
t = (1, 2, [3,4])
t[2] += [5, 6]
```

For those who don't know, it will raise an error, but will change the tuple.

I don't understand 2 things:

1. Why `t[2].extend([5, 6])` will work, without any errors?
2. Why an insert of new entry to dictionary will work without any error:

   `t = (1, {})
   t[1]["name"] = "bob"`

Comment: [If in Python I put a list inside a tuple, can I safely change the contents of that list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26262813/2301450)

Comment: 1. Because that's not trying to assign to `t[2]`. 2. Because dictionaries are also mutable, and again you're not trying to assign to a tuple element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because with `extend` and the dict you're mutating the objects themselves after retrieving them, rather than trying to assign to the tuple.

```
t[2] += [5, 6]
```

is actually kind of equivalent to

```
t[2] = t[2] + [5, 6]
```

which is clearly not allowed. (This calls `__setitem__` under the hood)

However, `t[2].extend([5, 6])` only gets the item (using `__getitem__`, which is permitted), and once it has the object is uses `extend`. The object is still the same object though - you may think of it as the pointer not having changed.

The case in your comment is an interesting one - again, it gets the object in the first statement `b = t[2]` and then already having the object mutates the object itself. You can see that this won't result in any call to the tuple's `__setitem__`. Refer to the dupe link for info on why it's possible to mutate tuple elements.

Comment: But when I'm doing `b = t[2]` and then `b += [5, 6]`, it's changing the tuple too.

Comment: Thats what I was missing the `setitem`